# time freezing doesn't work with pandas timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, freezegun

I've noticed this behaviour since at least 2015 and it hasn't changed since. When freezegun (or pytest-freezegun) is used to freeze time in a test, `datetime.datetime.now()` returns the frozen value while `pd.Timestamp('now')` and `pd.to_datetime('now')` do not. Is there a way around this?

For example: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-freezegun/

Comment: Hey s5s, did you ever find out how to circumvent this?

Comment: @AlphaCR Late answer posted

Answer (score 0):

`freezegun` does not mock pandas methods. There is an [open pull-request](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/pull/426/files) providing that functionality, but it has been sitting there for almost a year now, so I'm not hopeful for it. As an alternative, you could use the project [time-machine](https://pypi.org/project/time-machine/) which mocks at a lower level, in a way which will affect pandas.

The usage is similar, context-manager:

```
with time_machine.travel("2019-10-15 15:58:10Z"):
    datetime.now()
    pd.Timestamp("now")
```

Or decorator:

```
@time_machine.travel("2019-10-15 15:58:10Z")
def foo():
    ...
```